# How to create an overlay page in ionic 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

How to creating an transparent guide overlay page when i enter into new page

How can i implement in ionic 2 ?

[image]

Comment: Apparently there is a cordova plugin for that, https://github.com/souly1/ng-walkthrough. Took me a while to find!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can just create div outside the `<ion-content>`:

```
<div class="my-overlay" padding [hidden]="overlayHidden">
    <button full (click)="hideOverlay()">Click me</button>
</div>
```

with CSS:

```
.my-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  z-index: 20;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

In class declaration add (before constructor):

```
    overlayHidden: boolean = false;
```

and (after constructor):

```
public hideOverlay() {
    this.overlayHidden = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks This tour page so after install its show one time. how to circle that mark?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it correctly. You want to show it only once - probably on the first app run. Just use http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/nativestorage/ to store the data.

Comment: I used this solution but it will allow for scrolling events on the background, any ideas for that?