# Dynamically place an element in ionic2

Tags: javascript, css, html, angular, ionic2

My requirement here is to create a guide/walk-through for the app pages. Trying to achieve the guide/help page using an overlay. On first visit of the page i will show the overlay div similar to what has been described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221325/how-to-create-an-overlay-page-in-ionic-2). 
But my overlay contains some text box. I want to position the text relative to the base page element. Thus my queries are:

1. Can i get the absolute position of an element?
2. Can i programatically set the position co-ordinates of the element in overlay relative to position obtained #1.
3. If required, can i push an element (say a button) in overlay. e.g.: For certain guide I would like to have input from the user. Like I want to prompt user "Do you want to choose your level?" with 2 buttons yes/no. Based on input further action may be triggered.

Thanks in advance

Dhaval